# Java Browser handle button click

Tags: java, events

I need to open a browser with URL and then wait till person clicks a special button. And if it happens, return true. Can I implement it with java tools or should I use javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You should use JavaScript. Java is a Server side language, so all processing of Java code will be completed before the user has the chance to interact with the page. JavaScript (traditionally) works on the client-side and is commonly used to capture user interactions with the browser.

Answer (score 0):

yes, Java Script or any frame work that builds on Java script like Jquery works for you. If understands you correctly,

create Hyper link
Browse the page that you needed
Place HTML button on the page, write onClick logic on that button to return true.